# Deleting islands (lose parts) of mesh with Python

Tags: python, scripting

My Goal is it to remove Islands from an 3D scanned object (3D printer purpose) with python. I was thinking something like:

- Getting all vertices
- Iterate through all vertices

  - Save linked vertices and number of linked vertices
  - Remove all already scanned vertices from iteration
  - Compare with old maxLinked, if lower delete vertices

[image]

If someone could point me to a solution it would be great.

Comment: That can help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75332/how-to-find-the-number-of-loose-parts-with-python. But be aware calculation time will probably not be short...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the Separate into Loose Parts Operator.**

Possibly the quickest and simplest way to do this is to run the `bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')` operator to split the single mesh into loose parts.  Then remove all but the object with the most vertices.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
# edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
# split into loose parts
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
# object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

parts = context.selected_objects
# sort by number of verts (last has most)
parts.sort(key=lambda o: len(o.data.vertices))
# print
for part in parts:
    print(part.name, len(part.data.vertices))
# pop off the last
parts.pop()
# remove the rest
for o in parts:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(o)
```

There are a number of methods for doing this without the operator in answers to  [How to find the number of loose parts with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75332/how-to-find-the-number-of-loose-parts-with-python) including [my answer which returns a list of verts for each island in selection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105142/15543) which would be ideal for making an interactive tool to do this per selection, to clean "*splatter-cake*" verts.