# How to remove unlinked/disconnected parts of a bigger mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, objects, edit-mode, physics

I have many meshes like the one shown below which have some faces/vertices that are not connected to the main mesh. I use these meshes for physics simulation. As result of these weird parts of the meshes the physics simulation results becomes very different than what it is supposed to be. I wonder, what would be an effective solution to remove such parts?

I have tried "*Delete Loose*" in Edit Mode but it doesn't do the job. I was also thinking of writing a script to calculate the average of the faces and then remove the vertices that are further from that "average face" but I don't think this would work well based on my prior experience on doing a similar thing before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using 'delete loose' again but make sure you tick the 'Faces' box in the tools panel on the left.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105687/deleting-islands-lose-parts-of-mesh-with-python)

Comment: I had this issue before. You could go into Edit Mode and select the face of your main mesh and press Ctrl + L to select everything that is linked. Then press Ctrl + I to invert your selection and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I could recommend is to select the large object with the hotkey [L]. If there are several islands (isolated parts of the mesh) that you want in the physics simulation, you can select those too. once you have all of the mesh you want selected, then press control I (invert selection) and delete. That should get rid of any unconnected geometry

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit mode Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to be in wireframe mode. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left click</kbd> like lasso tool draw on unwanted verts you need to delete. After you draw it will select the verts Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and select verts.

[image]

Comment: I do not want to do this manually. As I said, I have many objects like this and doing this manually doesn't help me.

Comment: You can just do the above method to the main model and Press ctrl+I and reverse and delete it