# I am trying to create a Script that does a Smart UV unwrap of seperate connected parts of a mesh

Tags: python, uv

This is what I got so far. Note that I have a counter which I check with 10 while I'm testing, so it doesn't pass through everything, since it takes quite a while.

The reason for doing this is that if I select all and smart unwrap, I get a sub optimal result compared to the result I get when selecting each connected part and smart unwrap those parts separately, and then finally at the end, re-pack everything.

I am using this for light UV maps in UE4

Question 1) Seems the select-linked part doesn't work. What am I missing?

Question 2) Seems nothing gets unwrapped (is probably related to Q1)

```
def getNextVisibleVertex():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True , False , False)
    mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

    if hasattr(mesh.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
        mesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

    for vert in mesh.verts:
        if (not vert.hide):
            vert.select = True

            # Select linked
            bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
            for e in vert.link_edges: 
                e.select = True
            return True
    return False

def execute(self, context):
    obj = context.object
    data = obj.data
    i = 0

    found = getNextVisibleVertex()

    while (found and i < 10):
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
        bpy.data.objects[name].select = False
        # Hide selection so we don't pickup same 1st vertex next time
        bpy.ops.mesh.hide(unselected = False)
        i = i + 1

        found = getNextVisibleVertex()

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got something that works, it's slow as molasses, but works.

```
    def execute(self, context):     # execute() is called by blender when running the operator

        while (hasMoreVerts()):
            bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
            bpy.ops.mesh.hide(unselected = False)
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )

        return {'FINISHED'}         # this lets blender know that the operator finished successfully

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LightMapUVUnwrapper)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LightMapUVUnwrapper)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

def hasMoreVerts():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True , False , False)
    mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

    if hasattr(mesh.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
        mesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

    for vert in mesh.verts:
        if (not vert.hide):
            vert.select = True
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked()
            return True

    return false
```

Answer (score 2):

**Object mode bmesh script**

[image]
*Result of script run on default Cube, Cylinder and Icosphere joined as one object*

- Finds all the separate parts via the method outlined in [this
  answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105142/15543)
- The smart UV project operator appears to naff up an edit mode bmesh,
  so I went for object mode
- Find the islands and make a list of their vertices indices. *Hoping
  the uv operator doesn't mangle these*
- Use the islands to select vertices, and hence faces, write to mesh,
  toggle into edit mode and run the smart project for each island.

Have made a 3 in U grid of UVs per island.. find the islands again.. possibly could once again use the indices.. and shift the UVs using the island index.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

from time import time
t = time()

def walk_island(vert):
    ''' walk all un-tagged linked verts '''    
    vert.tag = True
    yield(vert)
    linked_verts = [e.other_vert(vert) for e in vert.link_edges
            if not e.other_vert(vert).tag]

    for v in linked_verts:
        if v.tag:
            continue
        yield from walk_island(v)

def get_islands(bm, verts=[]):
    def tag(verts, switch):
        for v in verts:
            v.tag = switch
    tag(bm.verts, True)
    tag(verts, False)
    ret = {"islands" : []}
    verts = set(verts)
    while verts:
        v = verts.pop()
        verts.add(v)
        island = set(walk_island(v))
        faces = set(f.index for x in island for f in x.link_faces if all(v.tag for v in f.verts) )
        ret["islands"].append(list(faces))
        tag(island, False) # remove tag = True
        verts -= island
    return ret

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (False, False, True)

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
islands = get_islands(bm, verts=bm.verts)["islands"]
off = [False] * len(me.polygons)

#bm.free()
bm.clear()
for island in islands:
    select = off[:]
    for i in island:
        select[i] = True
    me.polygons.foreach_set("select", select)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=True)

    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(toggle=True )

uv_arrange = False
cols, rows = (10, 10)
if uv_arrange:
    # arrange the UV islands

    bm.from_mesh(me)

    for i, island in enumerate(islands):

        # try and move uvs.. prob need to 
        bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()

        bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

        for f in [bm.faces[k] for k in island]:
            for l in f.loops:
                luv = l[uv_layer]
                if luv.uv.x > 1:
                    luv.uv.x %= 1
                luv.uv.x += i % cols
                luv.uv.y += i // rows
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()

print("Finished in ", time() - t, "secs")
```

EDIT.

Fixed a couple of things and optimized somewhat for speed.

**TESTING**

[image]
*Test Result 10 x 10 grid of UVs distributed*

Ran a simple test on an object made by applying array modifiers 10 in x 10 in y to produce a mesh with 100 separate cubes.
*Tests performed on an old Athlon, hopefully quicker on newer hw.*

This Answer.

```
Finished in  1.238006353378296 secs
Finished in  1.2316277027130127 secs
Finished in  1.2290542125701904 secs
```

with UV arranging

```
Finished in  1.2544517517089844 secs
Finished in  1.2524430751800537 secs
Finished in  1.2818937301635742 secs
```

On a 10 x 10 x 10 (1000) cube mesh. (no arranging)

```
Finished in  86.3908383846283 secs
```

[@Jonas Mølgaard](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133841/15543)

```
Finished in  1.4964582920074463 secs
Finished in  1.4645237922668457 secs
Finished in  1.4904592037200928 secs
```

On a 10 x 10 x 10 (1000) cube mesh.

```
Finished in  102.47884035110474 secs
```

** *added `bpy.ops.mesh.reveal()` call to unhide geometry to test multiple times*

EDIT

re [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133750/15543)

> *In the meantime i continued myself with my own version and currently have this now*
>      *... However, this crashes Blender for some reason.*

as mentioned above the smart uv operator trashes the edit bmesh, after which it becomes invalid.

Re [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133569/i-am-trying-to-create-a-script-that-does-a-smart-uv-unwrap-of-seperate-connected/133683?noredirect=1#comment229854_133683):

> *I tried your script, but it never ends. Either im doing something*
>   *wrong, or there's some assumption im not aware of.*

The proof of concept result of running script is displayed above for a simple mesh made from 3 primitives .

If you are testing on some monster multi part mesh put in the appropriate `if i > 10; break` The operator prints a message to system console, or put in print statements,  so you can see the progress.

You can stop a slow script by pecking at  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> into system console.

Comment: I tried your script, but it never ends. Either im doing something wrong, or there's some assumption im not aware of.

Comment: If i outcomment

Comment: about the smart uv operator that mess up the bmesh, is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Oh and btw, thanks for taking the time to help me out

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime i continued myself with my own version and currently have this now:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True , False , False)
mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

if hasattr(mesh.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    mesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

for vert in mesh.verts:
    if (not vert.hide):
        vert.select = True
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked()
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
        bpy.ops.mesh.hide(unselected = False)
```

However, this crashes Blender for some reason. If i insert a break at the end of the if (not vert.hide) block, it does what it should for 1st set of verts, and if i keep re-running the script, it also works fine, but that's ofc not funny when i have to do that about 400+ times pr. object. So what am i missing since this won't run?

Comment: If i outcomment bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() then it runs and the result is that everything is eventually hidden (as i would expect), but ofc, nothing is unwrapped. So seems i need to "reset" something for the bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() to work inbetween each iteration?