# Vert that have more than N edges connected to it

Tags: mesh, topology

I`m trying to find a solution (add-in or Py script) that will highlight the verts in a mesh that has more than N edges connected to it.

[image: for example i would like to find the indicated vert as a script output for "more than 5" edges connected.]

In the example below l indicated the vert, that have 6 edges connected to it.
It will be great if there is some solution to automate this type of check routine.

Comment: Take a look at this answer - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205436/75504 - it should help you find poles (verts with more than 4 edges).

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

and you could give a shortcut to "amount of connecting edges" so you could access it quicker

Comment: thats a good tool, but it needs an "example" mesh - some test geomerty. it will be great if there will be some window poping up asking the ammount of edges i am looking for.
the good example of user friendly interface for this tool is "select faces by sides" inteface.